# How to save an image in mongodb as a BLOB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, blob, buffer

I have completed a personal project in which a user can register themself and their profile picture get saved to the local disk, using multer, and an image url path is returned to the user. Everything is working flawlessly.

After completing this project, I've realized that storing the profile picture as a BLOB in mongodb seems a better approach because the image itself would be small and the data is placed in one place, instead of the image file on disk and the image url in mongodb. So, I'm basically attempting to accomplish this project, however, I'm a little overwhelmed by the terms buffer, blob and base64. Can someone please help explain the difference between these and which one should I use for storing the profile pic image in mongodb. Also, i'll be using mongoose and since it doesn't have a "blob" schema type so i'm assuming i would need to use the "buffer" schema type.

Lastly, can you also please show me how to convert an image to a blob or buffer and convert it back so it can be used as an img source. And, do I need to use multer?

Comment: Please show us the code that you currently have so the folks can try to help you better.

Comment: @MuhammadHamidRafique I don't have any code for this approach yet. As you can read in my question, firstly I need to figure out whether i'm storing a blob or a buffer in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to keep it short because there is a ton of material available online on these topics. It's okay to feel overwhelmed at first, but to be honest, it's neither that difficult nor that time-consuming to wrap your head around eventually.
Base64 is an encoding method that transforms data into a special set of 1's and 0's. A buffer is a designated memory area that stores this binary data for the processor to access and work with. A Blob (Binary Large Object) is a data type typically used in databases to store binary data. 
Since Mongoose doesn't have a specific blob schema type, you can use the buffer schema type to store binary data like images.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  profilePicture: Buffer // Store the profile picture as a buffer
})

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

module.exports = User
```

To convert an image to a buffer in Node.js, you can use a module like fs to read the image file and then store it as a buffer.

```js
const fs = require('fs');

// Read the image file and store it as a buffer
const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync('path/to/image.jpg')
```

To convert a buffer back to an image source that can be displayed in an HTML img tag, you can use the data URI scheme with Base64 encoding.

```js
// Convert the buffer to a Base64-encoded data URI
const base64Image = imageBuffer.toString('base64')
const imageSrc = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64Image}`

// Now you can use `imageSrc` as the source in an <img> tag in your HTML
```

Regarding the use of Multer, it's not strictly necessary for storing images as buffers in MongoDB. Multer is typically used when you want to handle file uploads from the client side and save them as separate files on your server's local disk. If you're not storing images as files on the disk and instead directly saving them as buffers in the database, you can skip using Multer for this specific use case. However, if you have other file upload requirements, Multer can still be a useful tool.